# Is there any way to include legend in the graph chart produced by open flash chart2?

Tags: charts, open-flash-chart

I am working on customizing the layout of OFC2 so it can be properly fit with my software. However, one of my concern of the chart is that, although it can generate multiple line graphs in the same pane, I haven't found where I could have the legend of the graph yet. (e.g. small description which tell that hollow purple line represent data A, yellow line represent data B and so on) Is there any way to actually doing this when I'm using line graphs? I have seen it is available in pie chart but it does not applied to graph chart BTW.

Comments, suggestion and even sample JSON would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "text" element inside your "elements"

eg: `"text": "Google Inc. (NASDAQ:GOOG)"`

Got this below eg from: http://demo.webasp.com.au/ofc-explorer-k.html

Eg JSON:

`{
  "title": {
    "text": "Google vs Apple Stock"
  },
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "text": "Google Inc. (NASDAQ:GOOG)",
      "font-size": 12,
      "values": [
        562.38,
        560.2,
        546.43,
        545.21,
        542.3,
        551,
        528.82,
        528.07,
        526.42,
        534.73,
        527.04,
        537,
        543.91,
        554.53,
        541.55,
        540.57,
        533.8,
        521.62,
        516.09,
        535.6,
        533.44,
        481.32,
        468.8,
        477.11,
        489.22,
        475.62,
        491.98,
        477.12,
        483.11,
        482.7,
        473.75,
        467.86,
        463,
        479.85,
        486.34,
        479.12,
        495.01,
        500.84,
        502.61,
        500.03,
        505.49,
        510.15,
        498.3,
        490.5,
        485,
        486.53,
        490.59,
        483.01,
        474.16,
        468.58,
        473.78,
        463.29,
        465.25,
        464.41,
        450.26,
        444.25,
        419.95,
        418.66,
        414.16,
        433.75,
        437.66,
        433.86,
        442.93,
        414.49,
        439.08,
        449.15,
        430.14,
        429.27,
        435.11,
        439.6,
        431.04,
        381,
        400.52,
        411.72,
        390.49,
        386.91,
        371.21,
        346.01,
        338.11,
        328.98,
        332,
        381.02,
        362.71,
        339.17,
        353.02,
        372.54,
        379.32,
        362.75,
        355.67,
        352.32,
        339.29,
        329.49,
        368.75,
        358,
        359.69,
        359.36,
        346.49,
        366.94,
        342.24,
        331.22,
        331.14,
        318.78,
        311.46,
        291,
        312.08,
        310.02,
        300.12,
        297.42,
        280.18,
        259.56,
        262.43,
        257.44,
        282.05,
        292.09,
        292.09,
        292.96,
        265.99,
        275.11,
        279.43,
        274.34,
        283.99,
        302.11,
        305.97,
        308.82,
        300.22,
        315.76,
        310.67,
        325.28,
        315.24,
        310.28,
        310.17,
        297.11,
        298.02,
        302.95,
        302.95,
        300.36,
        297.42,
        303.11,
        307.65,
        307.65,
        321.32,
        328.05,
        334.06,
        322.01,
        325.19,
        315.07,
        312.69,
        314.32,
        300.97,
        298.99,
        299.67,
        282.75,
        303.08,
        306.5,
        324.7,
        323.87,
        331.48,
        348.67,
        343.32,
        338.53,
        340.57,
        340.45,
        343,
        353.72,
        371.28,
        378.77,
        358.51,
        358.04,
        363.05,
        357.68,
        342.66,
        353.11,
        342.64,
        346.45,
        330.06,
        345.45,
        341.64,
        337.18,
        337.99,
        327.16,
        325.48,
        318.92,
        305.64,
        308.57,
        290.89,
        308.17,
        317.91,
        323.53,
        324.42,
        319.69,
        335.34,
        333.1,
        329.94,
        330.16,
        348.6,
        347.16,
        344.07,
        353.29,
        347.7,
        342.69,
        348.06,
        354.09,
        362.5,
        369.78,
        368.24,
        358.65,
        362,
        372.5,
        372.5,
        378.11,
        368.91,
        379.5,
        388.74,
        392.24,
        379.3,
        381.47,
        383.86,
        384.69,
        389.49,
        385.95,
        383.71,
        391.47,
        395.97,
        393.69,
        401.98,
        402.99,
        403.47,
        396.61,
        407.33,
        407.98,
        399.01,
        389.54,
        387.5,
        390,
        396.84,
        398.88,
        397.18,
        396.5,
        393.5,
        404.36,
        405.56,
        410.4,
        417.23,
        426.56,
        428.4,
        431.65,
        440.28,
        444.32,
        438.77,
        435.62,
        432.6,
        429,
        424.84,
        416.77,
        416
      ],
      "colour": "#3399FF",
      "dot-style": {
        "type": "line_dot",
        "tip": "#val# Google Inc. (NASDAQ:GOOG)<br>in Date #x_label#",
        "dot-size": 3,
        "colour": "#3399FF"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      "text": "Apple Inc. (NASDAQ:AAPL)",
      "font-size": 12,
      "values": [
        178.75,
        180.9,
        175.27,
        173.16,
        173.25,
        177.39,
        168.26,
        170.09,
        167.44,
        174.68,
        168.18,
        170.12,
        175.16,
        179.55,
        174.25,
        176.63,
        172.58,
        173.88,
        169.64,
        172.81,
        171.81,
        165.15,
        166.29,
        162.02,
        166.26,
        159.03,
        162.12,
        154.4,
        157.08,
        159.88,
        158.95,
        156.66,
        153.23,
        160.64,
        164.19,
        163.57,
        169.55,
        173.56,
        176.73,
        179.3,
        179.32,
        175.74,
        175.39,
        173.53,
        175.84,
        174.29,
        176.79,
        172.55,
        173.64,
        174.67,
        173.74,
        169.53,
        166.19,
        166.96,
        161.22,
        160.18,
        157.92,
        151.68,
        151.61,
        152.65,
        148.94,
        140.36,
        139.88,
        127.83,
        134.09,
        140.91,
        131.05,
        126.84,
        128.71,
        131.93,
        128.24,
        105.26,
        113.66,
        109.12,
        100.1,
        97.07,
        98.14,
        89.16,
        89.79,
        88.74,
        96.8,
        110.26,
        104.08,
        97.95,
        101.89,
        97.4,
        98.44,
        91.49,
        96.87,
        98.23,
        96.38,
        92.09,
        99.91,
        104.55,
        111.04,
        107.59,
        106.96,
        110.99,
        103.3,
        99.1,
        98.24,
        95.88,
        94.77,
        90.12,
        96.44,
        90.24,
        88.14,
        89.91,
        86.29,
        80.49,
        82.58,
        92.95,
        90.8,
        95,
        95,
        92.67,
        88.93,
        92.47,
        95.9,
        91.41,
        94,
        99.72,
        100.06,
        98.21,
        95,
        98.27,
        94.75,
        95.43,
        89.16,
        89.43,
        90,
        85.74,
        86.38,
        85.04,
        85.04,
        85.81,
        86.61,
        86.29,
        85.35,
        85.35,
        90.75,
        94.58,
        93.02,
        91.01,
        92.7,
        90.58,
        88.66,
        87.71,
        85.33,
        83.38,
        82.33,
        78.2,
        82.83,
        88.36,
        88.36,
        89.64,
        90.73,
        94.2,
        93,
        90.13,
        91.51,
        92.98,
        93.55,
        96.46,
        99.72,
        102.51,
        97.83,
        96.82,
        99.27,
        99.16,
        94.53,
        94.37,
        90.64,
        91.2,
        86.95,
        90.25,
        91.16,
        89.19,
        89.31,
        87.94,
        88.37,
        91.17,
        88.84,
        85.3,
        83.11,
        88.63,
        92.68,
        96.35,
        95.93,
        95.42,
        99.66,
        101.52,
        101.62,
        101.59,
        107.66,
        106.5,
        106.49,
        109.87,
        106.85,
        104.49,
        105.12,
        108.69,
        112.71,
        115.99,
        118.45,
        115,
        116.32,
        119.57,
        119.57,
        120.22,
        118.31,
        117.64,
        121.45,
        123.42,
        120.5,
        121.76,
        121.51,
        125.4,
        123.9,
        124.73,
        123.9,
        125.14,
        125.83,
        127.24,
        132.07,
        132.71,
        132.5,
        129.06,
        129.19,
        129.57,
        124.42,
        119.49,
        122.95,
        122.42,
        126.65,
        127.45,
        125.87,
        124.18,
        122.5,
        130.78,
        133.05,
        135.07,
        135.81,
        139.35,
        139.49,
        140.95,
        143.74,
        144.67,
        143.85,
        142.72,
        140.25,
        139.95,
        136.97,
        136.09,
        136.35
      ],
      "colour": "#663366",
      "dot-style": {
        "type": "line_dot",
        "tip": "#val# Apple Inc. (NASDAQ:AAPL)<br>in Date #x_label#",
        "dot-size": 3,
        "colour": "#663366"
      }
    }
  ],
  "x_legend": {
    "text": "Date",
    "style": "{color: #333333; font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;}"
  },
  "y_legend": {
    "text": "",
    "style": "{color: #333333; font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;}"
  },
  "bg_colour": "#ffffff",
  "x_axis": {
    "steps": 26,
    "labels": {
      "rotate": 0,
      "labels": [
        "06\/18\/08",
        "06\/19\/08",
        "06\/20\/08",
        "06\/23\/08",
        "06\/24\/08",
        "06\/25\/08",
        "06\/26\/08",
        "06\/27\/08",
        "06\/30\/08",
        "07\/01\/08",
        "07\/02\/08",
        "07\/03\/08",
        "07\/07\/08",
        "07\/08\/08",
        "07\/09\/08",
        "07\/10\/08",
        "07\/11\/08",
        "07\/14\/08",
        "07\/15\/08",
        "07\/16\/08",
        "07\/17\/08",
        "07\/18\/08",
        "07\/21\/08",
        "07\/22\/08",
        "07\/23\/08",
        "07\/24\/08",
        "07\/25\/08",
        "07\/28\/08",
        "07\/29\/08",
        "07\/30\/08",
        "07\/31\/08",
        "08\/01\/08",
        "08\/04\/08",
        "08\/05\/08",
        "08\/06\/08",
        "08\/07\/08",
        "08\/08\/08",
        "08\/11\/08",
        "08\/12\/08",
        "08\/13\/08",
        "08\/14\/08",
        "08\/15\/08",
        "08\/18\/08",
        "08\/19\/08",
        "08\/20\/08",
        "08\/21\/08",
        "08\/22\/08",
        "08\/25\/08",
        "08\/26\/08",
        "08\/27\/08",
        "08\/28\/08",
        "08\/29\/08",
        "09\/02\/08",
        "09\/03\/08",
        "09\/04\/08",
        "09\/05\/08",
        "09\/08\/08",
        "09\/09\/08",
        "09\/10\/08",
        "09\/11\/08",
        "09\/12\/08",
        "09\/15\/08",
        "09\/16\/08",
        "09\/17\/08",
        "09\/18\/08",
        "09\/19\/08",
        "09\/22\/08",
        "09\/23\/08",
        "09\/24\/08",
        "09\/25\/08",
        "09\/26\/08",
        "09\/29\/08",
        "09\/30\/08",
        "10\/01\/08",
        "10\/02\/08",
        "10\/03\/08",
        "10\/06\/08",
        "10\/07\/08",
        "10\/08\/08",
        "10\/09\/08",
        "10\/10\/08",
        "10\/13\/08",
        "10\/14\/08",
        "10\/15\/08",
        "10\/16\/08",
        "10\/17\/08",
        "10\/20\/08",
        "10\/21\/08",
        "10\/22\/08",
        "10\/23\/08",
        "10\/24\/08",
        "10\/27\/08",
        "10\/28\/08",
        "10\/29\/08",
        "10\/30\/08",
        "10\/31\/08",
        "11\/03\/08",
        "11\/04\/08",
        "11\/05\/08",
        "11\/06\/08",
        "11\/07\/08",
        "11\/10\/08",
        "11\/11\/08",
        "11\/12\/08",
        "11\/13\/08",
        "11\/14\/08",
        "11\/17\/08",
        "11\/18\/08",
        "11\/19\/08",
        "11\/20\/08",
        "11\/21\/08",
        "11\/24\/08",
        "11\/25\/08",
        "11\/26\/08",
        "11\/27\/08",
        "11\/28\/08",
        "12\/01\/08",
        "12\/02\/08",
        "12\/03\/08",
        "12\/04\/08",
        "12\/05\/08",
        "12\/08\/08",
        "12\/09\/08",
        "12\/10\/08",
        "12\/11\/08",
        "12\/12\/08",
        "12\/15\/08",
        "12\/16\/08",
        "12\/17\/08",
        "12\/18\/08",
        "12\/19\/08",
        "12\/22\/08",
        "12\/23\/08",
        "12\/24\/08",
        "12\/25\/08",
        "12\/26\/08",
        "12\/29\/08",
        "12\/30\/08",
        "12\/31\/08",
        "01\/01\/09",
        "01\/02\/09",
        "01\/05\/09",
        "01\/06\/09",
        "01\/07\/09",
        "01\/08\/09",
        "01\/09\/09",
        "01\/12\/09",
        "01\/13\/09",
        "01\/14\/09",
        "01\/15\/09",
        "01\/16\/09",
        "01\/20\/09",
        "01\/21\/09",
        "01\/22\/09",
        "01\/23\/09",
        "01\/26\/09",
        "01\/27\/09",
        "01\/28\/09",
        "01\/29\/09",
        "01\/30\/09",
        "02\/02\/09",
        "02\/03\/09",
        "02\/04\/09",
        "02\/05\/09",
        "02\/06\/09",
        "02\/09\/09",
        "02\/10\/09",
        "02\/11\/09",
        "02\/12\/09",
        "02\/13\/09",
        "02\/17\/09",
        "02\/18\/09",
        "02\/19\/09",
        "02\/20\/09",
        "02\/23\/09",
        "02\/24\/09",
        "02\/25\/09",
        "02\/26\/09",
        "02\/27\/09",
        "03\/02\/09",
        "03\/03\/09",
        "03\/04\/09",
        "03\/05\/09",
        "03\/06\/09",
        "03\/09\/09",
        "03\/10\/09",
        "03\/11\/09",
        "03\/12\/09",
        "03\/13\/09",
        "03\/16\/09",
        "03\/17\/09",
        "03\/18\/09",
        "03\/19\/09",
        "03\/20\/09",
        "03\/23\/09",
        "03\/24\/09",
        "03\/25\/09",
        "03\/26\/09",
        "03\/27\/09",
        "03\/30\/09",
        "03\/31\/09",
        "04\/01\/09",
        "04\/02\/09",
        "04\/03\/09",
        "04\/06\/09",
        "04\/07\/09",
        "04\/08\/09",
        "04\/09\/09",
        "04\/10\/09",
        "04\/13\/09",
        "04\/14\/09",
        "04\/15\/09",
        "04\/16\/09",
        "04\/17\/09",
        "04\/20\/09",
        "04\/21\/09",
        "04\/22\/09",
        "04\/23\/09",
        "04\/24\/09",
        "04\/27\/09",
        "04\/28\/09",
        "04\/29\/09",
        "04\/30\/09",
        "05\/01\/09",
        "05\/04\/09",
        "05\/05\/09",
        "05\/06\/09",
        "05\/07\/09",
        "05\/08\/09",
        "05\/11\/09",
        "05\/12\/09",
        "05\/13\/09",
        "05\/14\/09",
        "05\/15\/09",
        "05\/18\/09",
        "05\/19\/09",
        "05\/20\/09",
        "05\/21\/09",
        "05\/22\/09",
        "05\/26\/09",
        "05\/27\/09",
        "05\/28\/09",
        "05\/29\/09",
        "06\/01\/09",
        "06\/02\/09",
        "06\/03\/09",
        "06\/04\/09",
        "06\/05\/09",
        "06\/08\/09",
        "06\/09\/09",
        "06\/10\/09",
        "06\/11\/09",
        "06\/12\/09",
        "06\/15\/09",
        "06\/16\/09"
      ],
      "steps": 26
    },
    "colour": "#333333",
    "grid-colour": "#ffffff",
    "offset": false,
    "stroke": 1,
    "tick-height": 0
  },
  "y_axis": {
    "min": "0",
    "max": "600",
    "steps": 60,
    "colour": "#333333",
    "grid-colour": "#d9d9d9",
    "stroke": 0
  }
}`

Source